# Bigquery load from Avro gives can not convert from long to int

Tags: google-bigquery, avro, spark-avro

I am trying to load the avro file from google storage to Big query tables but faced these issue.
Steps i have followed are as below.

1. Create a dataframe in spark.
2. Stored these data by writing it into avro.

   dataframe.write.avro("path")
3. Loaded these data into google storage.
4. Tried to load the data into google bigquery by using following command

   bq --nosync load --autodetect --source_format AVRO datasettest.testtable gs://test/avrodebug/*.avro

This command leads to give this error.

*Error while reading data, error message: The Apache Avro library failed to read data with the follwing error: Cannot resolve: "long" with "int"*

So i even tried to use this command by specifying the schema.
     bq --nosync load --source_format AVRO datasettest.testtable gs://test/avrodebug/*.avro C1:STRING, C2:STRING, C3:STRING, C4:STRING, C5:STRING, C6:INTEGER, C7:INTEGER, C8:INTEGER, C9:STRING, C10:STRING, C11:STRING

Here i have only C6,C7 and C8 are having integer values. 
Even this also giving the same previous error.

**Is there any reason why i am getting error for long to int instead of long to INTEGER**

**Please let me know is there any way to load these data by casting it.**

Comment: It seems like you're loading multiple Avro files at the same time. In this case, the schema in the alphabetically last file is used to read all the files. The error indicates a field is type int in the last file, but type long in another file.

Comment: Thanks for the point.

Comment: However, to make it work i had to explicitly change the column type by loading individual Avro files as there is some pattern. And then i had to change the schema of the column by loading the data into separate table. I have followed this [Doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas) from google.

Comment: Both int and long are converted to int64 in BigQuery, so you should be able to load the Avro files into a same table. Have you tried that?
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-avro#avro_conversions

Comment: Yes I have tried the same thing by specifying int64 but it internally converts into INTEGER.